# SSL certificate conflict with traefik in docker environment

Tags: docker, ssl, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to set up a nextcloud docker container and access it via a traefik reverse proxy also running inside a container.

Now traefik takes care of SSL connections from outside to the server, that works fine. Up till now all other services I've set up only use non-encrypted connections between the rev proxy and the service. For this container I now wanted to setup SSL encryption also between the rev proxy and the nextcloud service.

The problem is, whenever I try to access the nextcloud service I get an "Internal Server Error".
I already figured out it has something to do with the SSL certificates, since when I used
"insecureSkipVerify" in the traefik configuration - thereby canceling SSL certificate verification - it worked fine. However that can obviously not be the right solution.

The certificates I'm using covers all used subdomains, so I'm using it for traefik and the nextcloud server. Might that be the problem?

Here's the nextcloud docker-compose part:

```
  nextcloud:
    image: linuxserver/nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    volumes:
      - nextcloudConfig:/config
      - nextcloudData:/data
      - ./my_stuff/certs/nas_server.crt:/config/keys/cert.crt:ro
      - ./my_stuff/certs/nas_server.key:/config/keys/cert.key:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - media
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-docker.rule=Host(`cloud.nas_server`)"
      - "traefik.docker.network=docker_services_media"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-docker.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.nextcloud-docker.loadbalancer.server.port=443"
      - "traefik.http.services.nextcloud-docker.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https"
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Which version of traefik do you use ?

Comment: Sorry for the omission: I'm using Traefik v2.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your traefik configuration, but this should help: https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#passthrough